# Calculations with binomial and decimal conversions

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics, network-flow

1KB=$2^{10}$ Bytes  and somehow 1KB/sec=$10^3$ Bytes/sec.
If you cancel out the sec$^{-1}$ on the second equation you get 1KB=$10^3$ Bytes. Can you please explain this to me? This is messing up all my homework conversions.  How does dividing a unit by seconds change it from binomial to decimal conversions?

The conflict that doesn't make sense to me is how: 
1KB = $2^{10}$B, but 1Mbps = $10^6$.

Comment: It’s very common for 1KB to denote 1,000 instead of 1,024, 1MB to denote 1,000,000 instead of 1,048,576, and so on. It’s just something you’ll have to figure out from context and deal with.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. 
The conflict that doesn't make sense to me is how:
1KB = 2^10B, but 1Mbps = 10^6.

Comment: @G.Shuster Technically $1 kB = 10^3 B$ vs. $1 KiB = 2^{10} B$. The [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) (such as *kibi*) have been standardized, but the industry was already (ab)using the decimal prefixes when that happened, and didn't follow suit for the most part.

Comment: @dxiv The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from.

Comment: @amd Right, of course. That said, given the `computer` tag, I suspect that part of the problem is in fact getting the units "right" in the context.